# Let's take a look at our Unanswered Questions list!

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

I know we're just at the start of public beta, but unanswered questions are always a good thing to keep an eye on :)

Right now there are only [9 questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on our Unanswered list; that's a manageable number to go through, and I think we should do so. A couple of the questions have 4 close votes; assuming we're in agreement that they're off-topic, one more close vote each will take care of the cleanup there.

For the rest of the questions, one has two answers (a question with answers can be on the Unanswered list, as long as none of the answers have upvotes). [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/525/how-many-distinct-unsolvable-rubiks-cubes-exist) is that question; it's about Rubik's Cubes. I don't know enough about them to contribute here, but if someone who does can either agree with one of the existing answers and upvote it, or write their own answer if the existing answers are wrong, we can get this question answered as well :)

The rest of them don't have answers yet, though some have quite a few upvotes. So the challenge here is to read through the rest of the questions on the unanswered list and decide 1) Is this a good question for the site? (If yes, upvote. If not, downvote and/or closevote). 2) Do I know the answer to this question? If so, post an answer!

The Unanswered tab is really useful because it helps us see questions we might have missed the first time around. We have pretty low question volume at this point, so we should be able to work together to keep an eye on this list. If we missed a question that's off-topic, we should work together to close it. If we missed a question we can answer, we should! And it's entirely possible that there will be some questions we just don't know the answers to (hopefully that'll change as we gather more experts!) But for now, the Unanswered list is a great thing to watch in our community.

So let's get to it!